# Form refuses to add first entry to cart and remove first entry from cart in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, routes

After redownloading my laravel project to my new pc from github, I got a new bug that didn't have before. The first entry of my shopping cart and of my products page can not go throught the assigned route given, but the rest of the entries work perfectly fine. I couldn't really find anything that resembled my problem in other questions.

This is the error message:
[image: The error in question]

I have tried to substitute the `Route::post` with `Route::match(['get', 'post']`, which solved the error, but had as a result that I couldn't add the first entry to the cart.

These are my routes before and after exchanging:

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login/authenticate', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('auth');
Route::get('/home', [PageController::class, 'home'])->name('home')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/products', [PageController::class, 'products'])->name('product')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::post('/products/addproduct', [OrderController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('addtocart')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::post('/products/removeproduct', [OrderController::class, 'removeFromCart'])->name('removefromcart')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/order', [PageController::class, 'order'])->name('order')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::post('/order/buy', [OrderController::class, 'payment'])->name('pay')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/orderhistory', function(){return view('orderHistory');})->name('orderhistory')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/products/details/{product}', [ProductDetailController::class, 'getProductPage'])->name('productdetail')->middleware('checklogin');

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/login/authenticate', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('auth');
Route::get('/home', [PageController::class, 'home'])->name('home')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/products', [PageController::class, 'products'])->name('product')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/products/addproduct', [OrderController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('addtocart')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/products/removeproduct', [OrderController::class, 'removeFromCart'])->name('removefromcart')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/order', [PageController::class, 'order'])->name('order')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/order/buy', [OrderController::class, 'payment'])->name('pay')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/orderhistory', function(){return view('orderHistory');})->name('orderhistory')->middleware('checklogin');
Route::get('/products/details/{product}', [ProductDetailController::class, 'getProductPage'])->name('productdetail')->middleware('checklogin');
```

This is the form I use to send the data to the route.

```
<div class="card-deck row">
                    @foreach (ProductController::getProduct() as $product)
                    @if($product->quantity > 0)
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 my-3">
                     <div class="card h-100 mx-2" style="width: 18rem;margin-bottom: -1em">
                       <form action="{{ route('addtocart') }}" method="post">
                        @csrf
                        <a href="products/details/{{$product->id}}" class="" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">
                          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
                            <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="{{$product->id}}">
                            <h5 class="card-title" name="product">{{$product->name}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text" name="description">{{$product->description}}</p>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                       <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                         <li class="list-group-item">

                          @if(count($product->categories) < 1)
                            No relevant categories found.
                          @else
                            @foreach ($product->categories as $category)
                              {{$category->name}}
                            @endforeach
                          @endif
                         </li>
                       </ul>
                       <div class="card-footer mt-auto">
                         <div class="input-group mb-3">
                         <input class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="{{$product->quantity}}">
                         <div class="input-group-append">
                         <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" value="Buy">
                          </div>
                       </div>
                       </div>
                     </form>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                     @endif
                     @endforeach
                  </div>
```

I have also no idea if this has anything to do with the function i use to add to or remove from the cart.

This is the function used to add the product to the cart and remove from the cart:

```
  public function addToCart(Request $request){
    $orderInfo = $this->getOrderInfo();
    if($orderInfo === null){
      $orderInfo = Order::create([
                         'customer_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                         'order_status' => 0
      ]);
    }
    if(Product::find($request->post('productId'))->quantity >= $request->post('quantity')){
      if($orderInfo->products->contains($request->post('productId')) === true){
        $orderInfo->products()->increment('order_quantity', $request->post('quantity'));
      }else{
        $orderInfo->products()->attach($request->post('productId'), ['order_quantity' => $request->post('quantity')]);
      }
      Product::where('id', $request->post('productId'))->decrement('quantity', $request->post('quantity'));
      return redirect(route('product'));
    }else{
      return "Product not in Stock";
    }
  }


  public function removeFromCart(Request $request){
    $orderInfo = $this->getOrderInfo();
    $orderQuantity = 0;
    foreach($orderInfo->products as $order){
      $orderQuantity = $order->pivot->order_quantity;
    }
    $orderInfo->products()->detach($request->post('delete'));
    Product::where('id', $request->post('delete'))->increment('quantity', $orderQuantity);
    return redirect(route('order'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After leaving this problem for what it is for a while, I came back to it to find out that the error code I had no longer appears and that everything works fine and as it should. I don't know what the problem was, nor do I know how it fixed itself.

**EDIT**

The error was caused by an unclosed `<form>` tag in the navbar of the project. After closing it off it resolved any route related error messages.